# Как запустить функцию один раз через таймер?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Нужно сделать так, чтобы функция запустилась один раз через 15 секунд, не используя time.sleep(), т.к. он замедляет всю работу скрипта.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
from threading import Timer

Timer(15, some_function).start()
```